# MongoDB setOnInsert and push if already existent

Tags: mongodb, upsert, database

I would like to add a document if it does not exist and else add an element to one of it's sub-documents.

```
db.test.update(
  {
    name : 'Peter'
  },
  $setOnInsert : { 
      name : 'Peter', 
      visits: { 'en' : ['today'], 'us' : [] }
  },
  $push : {
      visits.en : 'today'
  },
  { upsert : true }
)
```

If `Peter` exists, add an element to its `visists.en` or `visists.us` arrays. Else, create a document for `Peter`. This document should have the format for `visits` which should contain the current element (`'today'`).

My issue is that I have `"have conflicting mods in update"`.
I.e. (afaik), I cannot write to two things in one query. Yet how can I solve this dilemma?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could implement it without `$setOnInsert` operator.

```
db.test.update(
  {
    name : 'Peter'
  },
  {
    $push : {
      "visits.en" : 'today'
    }
  },
  { upsert : true }
)
```

If Peter exists, element `'today'` will be added to its `visits.en` array. Else, will be created a document for Peter, with `visits` object, that will be contain array `en` with `'today'` element.
And I think, that error occured because of you using same property (`visits`) in two operations (`$setOnInsert` and `$push`).

Comment: Sweet, I didn't know that it is possible to `$push` into not existing fields. This solves my troubles. I oversimplified my query a bit, so I need to stick to `$setOnInsert`. Instead I will simply remove `visits: { 'en' : ['today'], 'us' : [] }` from `$setOnInsert`.

Answer (score 5):

You can still use `$setOnInsert` but when `$setOnInsert` and `$push` doesn't updates in the same fields as mentioned before.

**N.b:** We use `$addToSet` if you don't want a duplicated values in your Array

```
db.test.update(
    {
      name : 'Peter'
    }, 
     {
      $setOnInsert: {name : 'Peter'},
      $addToSet: {"visits.en": 'today'} // or $push
     },
     {upsert: true})
```